# how to install Lexmark MS310Series V2XL printer driver in Libre Office in Ubuntu

Tags: gpu-driver, lexmark

Installation package for Lexmark MS310 Series printer in Win 10.

Lexmark_MS310_MS410_Series_ADT_Installation_Package.exe

Do you know of a similar package for UBUNTU?

P.

Comment: https://www.lexmark.com/es_es/printer/7696

Answer (score 0):

You find the drivers at this page

http://support.lexmark.com/index?linkSelected=node2%5Esubnode2&page=driversdownloads